# How to I take a part of a string from a google sheets cell which is in a pre defined dictionary and copy it to a different column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two columns in a sheet, one has has a name and a industry name combined in a string and both names are not necessarily limited to a certain number of words. I want to remove the industry name and put in the next column. I am new to google apps script, so need some help in the code to implement it. I have the industry names in a different column, so making a dictionary won't be an issue for the code.

It should work with google sheets.
[Sample input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/266M6.png)

Comment: Added an image for the input and output. Please check

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand what is your sample input and output situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function takepart(movethis = "fast") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let idx = r[0].toString().indexOf(movethis);
    if (~idx) {
      sh.getRange(i+ 1,1).setValue(r[0].toString().slice(0,idx) + r[0].toString().slice(idx + movethis.length))
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(r[1] + movethis);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked with a few tweeks